# LinkedIn API returns Positions without Title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, linkedin-api

An user of our app has noticed a problem with LinkedIn, he has 4 positions and 2 of these positions get returned without an title:

[image]

Also the connection profile seems ok:

[image]

I even logged in with his LinkedIn profile to check that he has filled in everything correctly and as far as I can see he has.

For retrieving the data from LinkedIn I am using the following gem:
https://github.com/hexgnu/linkedin

And running:

- Ruby 1.9.3p551
- Rails 3.2.19

EDIT1:

I checked the App on LinkedIn Developer site, both r_fullprofile and r_basicprofile are checked.

Comment: No response from #linkedin ?